# MacOs: avoid warnings for accessing folders

Tags: macos

We have a macOS application that searches the home directory for Git repositories. This causes macOS 10.15+ to pop up multiple confirmation dialogs. How to prevent that - with some notarization option?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/395631/allow-all-applications-to-access-desktop-documents-and-downloads-in-catalina

Comment: @pkamb Thanks for the link, but I don't want the users to do that, but my app should be somehow certified to allow accessing directories in the home directory. How developers of a file manager do that?

Comment: You won't be able to prevent these alerts. They're a security feature of the operating system.